# How to install PHP extensions on Cloudbees?

Tags: cloudbees

I need to install mbstring (and a few other extensions) for PHP on Cloudbees. Is this possible?

Note that I'm using an updated PHP version as described here:
https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/PHP+Builds

I don't think scripts have sudo access, so I can't simply use the package manager. I don't think these extensions exist as PEAR packages either. So I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from Cloudbees support. Seems to work fine, just make sure you don't have any spaces in your Jenkins build path!

Our provided PHP versions don't have mbstring module activated. You will need to build your own PHP version to get it. To be sure your custom PHP build works on Cloudbees slave, you can build it with a Jenkins job on your instance (with various --with-XXX or --without-XXX options).

We are ourselves doing something like this with a script like

```
# Download
regex='.*(RC|alpha|beta).*'
if [[ $version =~ $regex ]]; then
    wget http://downloads.php.net/dsp/php-${version}.tar.bz2
else
    wget http://us3.php.net/distributions/php-${version}.tar.bz2
fi

# Unpack
tar xjf php-${version}.tar.bz2

# Build
cd php-${version}
./configure --prefix=/home/jenkins/tools/php/${php_name} \
    --with-curl --with-openssl
make && make install
```

As a side node, you should also take care of specifying a good installation prefix with --prefix. I would choose something like /home/jenkins/tools/php/5.4/.

To store compiled php engine you could generate a tar.gz//bz2 file of target installation directory. Then, store it in your WebDAV directory, which is accessible in /private/{account}/ during a build when "Mount CloudBees DEV@cloud Private WebDav Repository" is checked.

You should add a first step to jobs requiring PHP to extract this archive. As Jenkins workspace is usually cached on DEV@Cloud, you can extract the archive only if it's not already there. That will speed up your build.